# Why is this impl trait getting `cannot return without recursing` error?

Tags: rust

To avoid the "use of unstable library feature 'command_access'" error, I'm not using [get_envs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/25a277f03df7e44643ddfcc240d034409cb2f505/library/std/src/sys/unsupported/process.rs#L63) directly, but using Trait to abstract it.

Why do I get a "recursive call site" error in the following code below?

```
use std::process::Command;

pub trait Envs {
    type Item;
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;

    fn get_envs(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}

impl Envs for Command {
    type Item = OsString;
    type Iter = vec::IntoIter<OsString>;

    fn get_envs(&self) -> <Command as ProcessEnvs>::Iter {
        self.get_envs() // recursive call site
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't bypass unstable APIs this way. You can't call unstable fns without using the feature, PERIOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the error message is misleading.

What is happening here is that `Command::get_envs` is a nightly-only api that hasn't been stabilized yet.

Due to this, when you call `self.get_envs()`, the compiler assumes the method doesn't exist and calls the trait method instead.

In beta and nightly, the api is now stable and can be used without any `#![feature(...)]`. It will likely be stabilized soon, since it was stabilized in beta.

The following is a solution to your code that works in beta / nightly and will start working in the future:

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::vec;
use std::ffi::OsString;

pub trait Envs {
    type Item;
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;

    fn get_envs(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}

impl Envs for Command {
    type Item = OsString;
    type Iter = vec::IntoIter<OsString>;

    fn get_envs(&self) -> <Command as Envs>::Iter {
        self.get_envs().map(|(s, _)| s.to_os_string()).collect::<Vec<_>>().into_iter()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=97b9069baf0d0ec7b56a6d9648a73457)

Answer (score 3):

When you call `envs.get_envs()`, it's going to return `self.get_envs()`.

To compute the result of `self.get_envs()`, it's going to call `self.get_envs()`.

To compute the result of `self.get_envs()`, it's going to call `self.get_envs()`.

Etc...

This is essentially equivalent to:

```rust
fn foo() -> i32 {
  foo()
}
```

Perhaps you meant to actually interact with `std::env` somewhere here?